# Recommended way to change database in existing connecction with node-mysql

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to change database in an existing connection in node.
The connection may or may not have database name in `createConnection` call.
Here's the code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');


connection = mysql.createConnection( {
    host               : 'localhost',
    user               : 'me',
    password           : 'secret',
    port               : 3306,
    /* database           : 'test' // optional */
});
```

I am using node-mysql lib.
Currently I'm closing the connection and re-connecting.

Is there any better way to do that? Similar to `mysql_select_db` in php?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change some of the connection parameters* with the [`changeUser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#switching-users-and-altering-connection-state) method:

```
connection.changeUser({database : 'my_database'}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

*List of these parameters:

- `user`: The name of the new user (defaults to the previous one).
- `password`: The password of the new user (defaults to the previous one).
- `charset`: The new charset (defaults to the previous one).
- `database`: The new database (defaults to the previous one).

Comment: How can I switch the database in a connection pool?

Comment: @HelloWorld see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56146932/4074148) to switch the database in a connection pool. Note that I agree with the end note avise about having a connection pool per database, rather than a common pool where you change the database.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I have found is to use the 'USE' command

in  your example it would look like this

```
let database = 'my_database';
connection.query(`USE ${database}`, (error, results, fields) => {
    ...
  });
```

after that all queries using this connection would be sent to the new database

Answer (score 1):

Or just use database name in query

```
conn.query('SELECT H FROM other.GeoDB WHERE H = \'r1r0f\' LIMIT 1  ', function (err, res, f)
conn.query('SELECT * FROM data.users WHERE U = \'123\' LIMIT 1  ', function (err, res, f)
```