# Switch database in a connection pool in nodejs MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, connection-pooling

How can I switch the database after connecting to MySQL in nodejs using connection pool?

I used to use the normal connection with MySQL since it has some [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097055/protocol-enqueue-after-fatal-error-nodejs-mysql) now I would like to use the connection pooling. But how can I change the database after creating a connection with MySQL?

Here is how I change the database:

```
conn.changeUser({
    database: req.session.dbname
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

**But now it shows `conn.changeUser` is not a function**

Here is the method to connect with mysql:

```
const conn = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: config.host,
    user: config.user,
    password: config.password,
    database: 'shaw_elc_gst_13032019'
});
```

**This is the result when I `console.log(conn)`:**

```
Pool {
  _events:
   [Object: null prototype] {
     connection: [Function],
     acquire: [Function],
     enqueue: [Function],
     release: [Function],
     error: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 5,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  config:
   PoolConfig {
     acquireTimeout: 10000,
     connectionConfig:
      ConnectionConfig {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        localAddress: undefined,
        socketPath: undefined,
        user: 'root',
        password: '****',
        database: 'shaw_elc_gst_13032019',
        connectTimeout: 10000,
        insecureAuth: false,
        supportBigNumbers: false,
        bigNumberStrings: false,
        dateStrings: false,
        debug: undefined,
        trace: true,
        stringifyObjects: false,
        timezone: 'local',
        flags: '',
        queryFormat: undefined,
        pool: [Circular],
        ssl: false,
        multipleStatements: false,
        typeCast: true,
        maxPacketSize: 0,
        charsetNumber: 33,
        clientFlags: 455631 },
     waitForConnections: true,
     connectionLimit: 10,
     queueLimit: 0 },
  _acquiringConnections: [],
  _allConnections:
   [ PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11069,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11067,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11070,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11068,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11071,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11072,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11073,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11074,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11075,
       _pool: [Circular] },
     PoolConnection {
       _events: [Object],
       _eventsCount: 2,
       _maxListeners: undefined,
       config: [ConnectionConfig],
       _socket: [Socket],
       _protocol: [Protocol],
       _connectCalled: true,
       state: 'authenticated',
       threadId: 11076,
       _pool: [Circular] } ],
  _freeConnections: [],
  _connectionQueue:
   [ [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function],
     [Function] ],
  _closed: false }
```

Comment: Could you try debugging and see what's the value for conn? Because such errors like this is not a function usually occurs only when it is not the required object, here it means conn may not be a connection object.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan but when I am executing a query using `conn.query` it works fine!!

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using? And also did you try debugging and see if there's a function called change user in the object, it might give you some insight.

Comment: mysql 5.7 i am using

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan I have updated the question! Pls check

Comment: I forgot to ask for the version of mysql driver also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193382/discussion-between-hello-world-and-kiran-mathew-mohan).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest giving the [pooling documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections) a thorough read.

You've said you're using `conn.changeUser(/*...*/)`, but then you've said you're using `const conn = mysql.createPool(/*...*/);` to initialize that `conn` constant. That means `conn` is a *pool*, not a connection; it's not surprising that it doesn't have a `changeUser` method.

If you want to change database, you need to do it on the connection, not the pool. Instead of using the shorthand `pool.query` form, you'd do `pool.getConnection`/`conn.changeUser`/`conn.query`/`conn.release`. First, call your variable `pool`, not `conn`:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
```

then

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        // handle/report error
        return;
    }
    conn.changeUser({
        database: req.session.dbname
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // handle/report error
            return;
        }
        // Use the updated connection here, eventually
        // release it:
        conn.release();
    });
});
```

**That said**, if it were me, I'd be more comfortable having a connection pool per database, rather than a common pool where you change the database. That could be pure paranoia on my part, but it's what I'd do. But if you don't use separate pools, I suggest always do the `changeUser` so you're sure what database you're using, or test *thoroughly* to see what the `mysql` module does to handle this (and repeat that testing on every dot release of the module, unless the maintainer documents the behavior).