# Switching databases in a MySQL pool: changeUser vs use database

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering which approach is better for switching databases...

The idea is to get the database name from a subdomain, and make the specific route SQL query use that databases, until a request comes from another subdomain.

This switch will happen constantly depending on each API request.

## [changeUser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56146932/3878760)

This can be a middleware before each API route.

```js
pool.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        // handle/report error
        return;
    }
    conn.changeUser({
        database: req.session.dbname
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            // handle/report error
            return;
        }
        // Use the updated connection here, eventually
        // release it:
        conn.release();
    });
});
```

## USE DATABASE

Simply prepend each query with the `USE` statement. This can also be a middleware.

```sql
USE specific_db;

select * from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to switch to a different default database, I'd use `USE`. This preserves your session, so you can continue a transaction, or use temporary tables or session variables. Also your user privileges remain the same.

`changeUser()` starts a new session, optionally you can change user, or change the default database. But any session-scoped things such as I listed above are ended.

I don't think we can say either is "better" because they are really different actions, each suited to their own purpose. It's like asking whether `if()` is better than `while()`.

---

So it depends what is the purpose for the change in your case. You have clarified in the comments that you are doing this in middleware at the time you handle a new request.

It's important to avoid leaking information between requests, because session variables or temp tables might contain private data for the user of the previous request. So it's preferred to reset all session-scoped information. `changeUser()` will accomplish that, but `USE` won't.

My analogy is that `changeUser()` is like logging into Linux potentially as a different user, but `USE` is like staying in the same Linux shell session, but simply using `cd` to change directory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I apologize for the lack of clarity. I've updated my question to specify that I will switch the databases based on a subdomain, and constantly keep switching it with every API request.

Comment: Then it sounds like it's desirable to isolate each request from the previous and next request, to ensure no data leaks into different users' requests.

Comment: Does that mean `changeUser` user is prefetanle? Please add an answer so I can accept it.